# EF and WinForms - maintaining a static list of entities

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I am using EF 5.0 in a WinForms application. I dispose the DBContext quick.

Nevertheless I must maintain a static list of `Customer` entities , which I populate on startup using a DBContext - again, disposed quickly. Plus, I slighlty use multi-threading in some parts of the application.

The issue is that I receive this exception every once and then:

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of
>   IEntityChangeTracker.

Should I detach every `Customer` in that static list before disposing the DBContext? Should I use some other design for a WinForms application? I appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use AsNoTracking method when querying instances: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352(v=vs.103).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Consider building [Data Transfer Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) to make a clean separation between EF and the static list.

The main benefit of this is limiting EF's influence on the rest of the application.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use a list of `Customer` entity objects, but some mirror type, say `CustomerListItem`.

You can populate the list by projecting `Customer`s into the items

```
db.Customers.Select(c => new CustomerListItem { Name = c.Name, ... })
```

By doing this you create objects that are not tracked. And you will be sure that changes in the entity model will not affect other parts of the application that depend on the customer list. *And* you will not run into potential lazy loading exceptions (if `Customer` has lazy navigation properties).

As it is a static list accessible to the whole application I would use a [`ReadOnlyCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx).